# can I chage url for register_post_type

Tags: custom-post-types, urls

I registered custom post type by `register_post_type('new_post',$args);` So new post url looks like `http://myweb.com/new_post/post_name

Can I change **_*later*_** the part of url from `new_post` to something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would help if you listed your $args array, but, the portion you are looking for is under 'rewrite'. Here's the way I like to build an $args array for registering a post type:

```
// set up the labels
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Archived Jobs', 'post type general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Archived Job', 'post type singular name'),
        'add_new' => __('Add New'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Job'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Job'),
        'new_item' => __('New Job'),
        'view_item' => __('View Job'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Jobs'),
        'not_found' =>  __('No Jobs found'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Jobs found in Trash'), 
        'parent_item_colon' => '',
        'menu_name' => 'Archives'
    );
//set up the rewrite rules
    $rewrite = array(
        'slug' => 'archives'
    );
//build the arguement array
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true, 
        'show_in_menu' => true, 
        'query_var' => 'archives',
        'rewrite' => $rewrite,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'has_archive' => true, 
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => null,
        'supports' => array('title','editor','author','comments')
    ); 
    register_post_type('archive',$args);
```

The portion of this you are looking for is the $rewrite part, change the slug to whatever you want (url friendly of course, no weird characters or spaces). You may even wish to put slashes in there. In my example, a URL reads: www.website.com/archives/post_name/

Comment: Don't get to visit the permalinks page to(else the post type rewrite rules aren't updated).

Comment: @t31os: Dont *forget* to visit the page, I assume?

Comment: @Jan - Indeed... not spotted in time for a ninja edit though.. :(

Comment: Remember that when you change the URL structure, the existing posts will use the new URLs too, and the old URLs will no longer work. If this is a problem you should add redirects from the old to the new URLs.

Comment: @Drew, @t31os, @Jan what confuses me is if I can change the url structure after I create custom post type. If yes, how? And what I have do after that.

Comment: @Drew: if I understood right I can use your code to create new post type and use (almost) whatever text for slug. But what I want to change it later on?

Comment: That's why I didn't post $arg I use, I want to know if I can change slug later ...

Comment: Yeah, you can change it, as long as you flush the rewrite rules.